# Unable to translate in angular using angular translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

```
$scope.barChartData.labels.push(moment(currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "  
$filter('translate')('To')" + moment(currentDate).add(4, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

trying to translate "To" word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing this 2 lines, i found that you are using lib [chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs)

for generating chart in angularjs app. And it create a svg based on data provided. So you need to again reload that svg in html with the same process of creating svg so that it is  use translation based on language selection at that time.
Let me know if this solves the issue.